# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (wrong name )

Tags: java, jfilechooser, urlclassloader

I have run the application to load a class name called ChocolateMilk.java inside the netbeans project, I want to call this class using JFileChooser and then load it using ClassLoader.

here is the code for the method to get filename which is inside main class.

```
public static String getTheFileName() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        JFileChooser jfc = new  JFileChooser();
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(fc.FILES_ONLY);
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "build"+ File.separator + "classes"));
        jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        File myfile ;

String fileNameWithOutExt = jfc.getName((myfile = jfc.getSelectedFile()));
        int pos = fileNameWithOutExt.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0) {
            fileNameWithOutExt = fileNameWithOutExt.substring(0, pos);
        }
FilenameUtils.removeExtension(jfc.getName((myfile = jfc.getSelectedFile())));

        System.out.println("the program name is " +fileNameWithOutExt);
        return fileNameWithOutExt;
 }
```

I am calling getTheFileName method as a parameter for method called run inside foodProcessorEnvironmentA Class.

```
foodProcessorEnvironmentA.run(getTheFileName());
```

## Here is the full code for the run method.

```
public void run(String programName) {
                URLClassLoader classLoader ;
    // the class path is a string that inside foodProcessorEnvironmentA class as URL instance variable 


  classLoader = new URLClassLoader(classPath);
            Class prgramClass = null;

            try {
                prgramClass = classLoader.loadClass(programName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FoodProcessorEnvironmentA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            AbstractFoodProcessorProgram program = null;
            try {
                program = (AbstractFoodProcessorProgram) prgramClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FoodProcessorEnvironmentA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FoodProcessorEnvironmentA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            program.setEnvironment(this);

            program.start();

    //        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

==========================

this is the output after running the project.

=============================

```
The fileName is: file:/Users/****/Desktop/FoodProcessor/build/classes/foodprocessor/
the program name is ChocolateMilk
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ChocolateMilk (wrong name: foodprocessor/ChocolateMilk)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at foodprocessor.FoodProcessorEnvironmentA.run(FoodProcessorEnvironmentA.java:31)
    at foodprocessor.FoodProcessor$1.run(FoodProcessor.java:191)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

===========

I hope my question is clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the filename to `Class.forName()` in a form that corresponds to the fully-qualified class name including the package. In this case, `foodprocessor.ChocolateMilk.` You would need to know where the head of the package structure is in the file system; use that as the URL provided to the `URLClassLoader;` and then call `loadClass("foodprocessor.ChocolateMilk")`.

Comment: I know this is the easy way to do it, but I have another class other than ChocolateMilk, that's why I am using JFileChooser. I have to use JFileChooser. thanks EJP for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by having a concatenation of a string of the package name with the dot and the programName variable.

here

```
prgramClass = classLoader.loadClass("foodprocessor."+programName);
```

That's it!